# starting marionette modules with requirejs

Tags: javascript, requirejs, marionette

There is something I don't really understand about using requirejs with marionettejs.

So I'm trying to use marionette module with requirejs.

```
//app.js
define(["marionette"], function(Marionette){

    var App = new Marionette.Application();
    App.startSubApp = function(appName, args) {...}
    App.on("initialize:after", function(){
        require(["app/module1"], function () {
            Backbone.history.start();
            App.startSubApp("module1");
        });
    }
});



//module1.js
define(["app"], function(App){

    App.module("module1", function(Module1, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _){
        Module1.startWithParent = false;

        Module1.onStart = function(){
            console.log("starting module1");
        };
    }


});
```

The problem is that the onStart handler was never triggered because inside App.startSubApp, module1 is already instantiated.

I managed to fix the problem by calling startSubApp in module1.js instead:

```
//app.js
define(["marionette" , 'vent'], function(Marionette, vent){

    var App = new Marionette.Application();
    App.startSubApp = function(appName, args) {...}
    App.on("initialize:after", function(){
        require(["app/module1"], function () {
            Backbone.history.start();
            vent.trigger("start:module1");
        });
    }
});


//module1.js
define(["app",'vent'], function(App, vent){

    App.module("module1", function(Module1, App, Backbone, Marionette, $, _){
        Module1.startWithParent = false;
        Module1.onStart = function(){
            console.log("starting module1");
        };
    }
    vent.on('start:module1', function(){
        App.startSubApp("module1");
    });
});
```

I"m fairly new to both requirejs and marionettejs so can someone explain to me the reason for this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to run code when an app (or module) starts up, both have initializer callbacks that you can add using [app.addInitializer()](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.md#adding-initializers) and [module.addInitializer()](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.application.module.md#module-initializers)